# Function decorators for std::bind in C++0x

Tags: c++11, bind, decorator, boost-asio

need a function wrapper for std::bind that will be called before the function it's wrapper, passing the arguments along to the wrapped functions.

```
std::function<void (int)> foo = postbind<int>(service, handle);
```

That's as far as I've got too. I'd like to make the postbind object auto-deduce the type. I've tried creating an object generator make_postbind(service, handle) but it was unable to deduce the types automatically.

Below I've written a test case. Compiles using: g++ -o postbind postbind.cpp -std=c++0x -lboost_system

I'd like to get the line:

```
std::function<void (int)> func = postbind<int>(strand, std::bind(foo, myfoo(), 'a', _1));
```

Down to:

```
std::function<void (int)> func = postbind(strand, std::bind(foo, myfoo(), 'a', _1));
```

But am unsure how to. In my code, I'm starting to get some really lengthy postbind template specialisations that are beginning to [eat up my horizontal whitespace](https://gitorious.org/libbitcoin/libbitcoin/blobs/master/src/verify.cpp) :)

```
#include <boost/asio.hpp>
#include <thread>
#include <iostream>
#include <functional>
#include <memory>
using namespace boost::asio;
using std::shared_ptr;

typedef shared_ptr<io_service> service_ptr;
typedef shared_ptr<io_service::work> work_ptr;
typedef shared_ptr<io_service::strand> strand_ptr;
typedef std::shared_ptr<io_service::work> work_ptr;

using std::placeholders::_1;

template<typename... Args>
class postbind
{
public:
    typedef std::function<void (Args...)> function;

    postbind(strand_ptr strand, function memfunc)
      : strand_(strand), memfunc_(memfunc)
    {
    }

    void operator()(Args... params)
    {
        strand_->post(std::bind(memfunc_, std::forward<Args>(params)...));
    }
private:
    strand_ptr strand_;
    function memfunc_;
};

// --------------------------------------------

struct myfoo
{
    char a;
    int b;
};

void run(service_ptr service)
{
    service->run();
}

void foo(myfoo foo, char a, int x)
{
    std::cout << "this thread: " << std::this_thread::get_id() << "\n"
            << x << "\n";
}

int main()
{
    service_ptr service(new io_service);
    strand_ptr strand(new io_service::strand(*service));
    work_ptr work(new io_service::work(*service));
    std::thread t(std::bind(run, service));
    std::cout << "main thread: " << std::this_thread::get_id() << "\n";
    std::function<void (int)> func = postbind<int>(strand, std::bind(foo, myfoo(), 'a', _1));
    func(99);
    t.join();
}
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You could move your template specializations into another class so that you do not have to place them on your calls to `postbind`.  For instance, create an empty class who's purpose is to simply hold all the long drawn-out template arguments:

```
template<typename... Args>
struct post_bind_traits {};
```

Now somewhere else in your code (i.e., another file), you could setup all the versions of arguments you would need.  For instance, in a header file you could do the following:

```
typedef post_bind_traits<int, int> pb_int_int;
typedef post_bind_traits<double, int> pb_double_int;
//... additional definitions
```

Then you can create a partial template specialization of your `postbind` class that looks like the following:

```
template<typename... Args>
class postbind<post_bind_traits<Args...>> //add this partial specialization
{
public:
    typedef std::function<void (Args...)> function;

    postbind(strand_ptr strand, function memfunc)
      : strand_(strand), memfunc_(memfunc)
    {
    }

    void operator()(Args... params)
    {
        strand_->post(std::bind(memfunc_, std::forward<Args...>(params)));
    }
private:
    strand_ptr strand_;
    function memfunc_;
};
```

Now you can call `postbind`, provided you have access to the `typedef` definitions in the header files, like the following:

```
postbind<pb_int_int>::function func = postbind<pb_int_int>(/* arguments */);
```

Pack all the complicated `typedefs` in your header, and you'll have a much cleaner code-set in your main code-module files.

Answer (score 0):

I think the answer is no way. This is because of the difference between std::function and the return value of std::bind.

- The function signature of std::function must be specified while being declared.
- The signature of functor returned by std::bind has actually a variadic template arguments, which won't be decided until its operator() is invoked. It means that the signature is not unique at declaring time, which is definitely before evaluating time.

Look at the expected invocation, `std::function<void(...)> func = postbind(strand, std::bind(foo, myfoo(), 'a', _1);`. Actually, the compiler only knows the bound arguments and some placeholders. After a while, its operator() is invoked, then the unbound arguments are going to replace the placeholders, and now compiler can check whether all arguments matches the function signature or not.

If above sentences are too recondite to understand, please let me show some code:

```
void foo(int) {}

foo(1);          // Correct.
foo(1, 2);       // Illegal, signature mismatched.

auto f = std::bind(foo, _1);  // Here f has no idea about unbound args for foo.

f(1);         // OK, 1 matches int.
f(1, 2);      // OK too, although 2 is used.
f(1, 1, 1);   // Same as before ones.

auto func = postbind(
    strand, std::bind(foo, _1));    // If this is acceptable,

func(99);       // this is a correct invocation then.
func(99, 98);   // And this should also be happy for compiler. Ambiguity!
```

As a result, you have to specify the signature explicitly while binding.

But anyway, here's a code snippet which might be a substitute solution I guess:

```
template <typename... ArgTypes>
void do_post(strand_ptr strand, ArgTypes&&... args)
{
    strand->post(std::bind(std::forward<ArgTypes>(args)...));
}

int main()
{
    // some code

    auto original_closure = std::bind(foo, myfoo(), 'a', _1);
    auto final_closure = std::bind(
        do_post<decltype(std::ref(original_closure)), int>,  // signature deduced here
        strand, std::ref(original_closure), _1);  // std::ref used for inner std::bind
    final_closure(99);

    // others
}
```